# Position UILabel in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uilabel

I am trying to position a `UILabel` within a `UIView` on a storyboard, without any code.  I'd like the label to have an X position of 1/4 of the width of the `UIView`.  So, if the width of the `UIView` is 400, I want the `UILabel` to be at X = 100.

Is it possible to do this on the storyboard with constraints without code?

Comment: by position of the label, do you mean the location of its 'center'?

Comment: The position of its left is fine.  The width of the label is just enough for the character that I'm trying to position.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a constraint such that the leading edge of your label is equal to the trailing edge of your superview with a `constant` of `0` and a `multiplier` of `0.25`.

To create this in the *Storyboard*:

1. <kbd>control</kbd>-drag from the label to the right edge of its superview.
2. Choose *Trailing Space to Container* from the pop-up.
3. Now edit the constraint.  Click on the I-bar that connects your label to the right of its superview.  Open the *Attributes Inspector*.  Choose the *First Item* pop-up and select *Reverse First and Second Item*.
4. The *First Item* should now be the *Trailing* edge of your label.  Click on that and change it to *Leading*.
5. Change the *constant* to `0`.
6. Change the *multiplier* to `0.25`.  (Note: You can also use `1:4` or `1/4` if those seem more intuitive).

---

[image: Constraint in Storyboard]

Answer (score 1):

1. First give all other constrains to the `UILabel`.
2. to set **X position as 1/4 of the width of the UIView**

   Consider trailing margin of Superview. If trailing margin is 60, then width of the view will be 60

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a accessory `clear-color` view to help get that:

1. Firstly, create the `superview`(blue view), and set the `constraints`
   [image]
2. Secondly, you can use a `assist view`, set it's width is 1/4 of the blue view

1) When you set the `assist view`'s width constraint , you can drag the `assist view` to the `blue view`, choose the `Equals Width`, the in the `Size inspector` you can edit the width `constraint`'s Multiplier to be `1:4`

[image]

2) Set the `assist view`'s background color to be clear

[image]

The result is this:

[image]

3. The third step, you can drag the `label`, set the `label`'s left `constaint` to the `assist view`
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answer below what you can do is add a *bottom* and *trailing* of your `UILabel` to your *superview*. Now control-drag your `UILabel` to your *superview* and select the *equal width* constraint and set the multiplier to 0.75.

The above will allow your your `UILabel` to always have a width of 3/4 to your *superview* and since it will have a trailing of 0 to your *superview* there will always be a space offset by 1/4 the width of your *superview*